# HTML page on remote server does not load

Tags: javascript, html, security

I am doing a local HTML page that will run inside a kind of kiosk. This page is the first page to  load, `index.html`.

This page shows a menu where the user has to choose a language.

When the user clicks on an icon and chooses a language, a page opens in the remote server, over https.

This second page, let's call it `second.html`, shows the videos in the language chosen.

The problem is that the kiosk refuses to show `second.html`. It gives me an error "page cannot be loaded error -6".

When I test it on a browser running on my computer, everything works perfectly.

The kiosk runs chromium web engine.

I have no means to debug that on the kiosk. The tool they have provided for debugging is not working properly.

Both pages, `index.html` and `second.html` load javascripts and css. For the first one the files are stored locally. For the other one, the files are located in the server.

`second.html` is being loaded by a link on `index.html`. No AJAX.

Is there any security thing that could prevent second.html from loading when clicked locally?

Comment: `second.html` is being loaded by link. What do you mean by the header thing?

Comment: I don't get it. If you can explain it in an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible causes I ran into:
If index.html is loaded on the kiosk from a locally running webserver the policy of that local server forbids loading content from other servers. Error 6 in android-based kiosk software is "error message of policy". The easiest way is to reconfigure the kiosk-software and/or the server it talks to - nothing you could solve if you have not access to both servers.
The second if the file is loaded from local file system can be missing/malformed CORS messages, or if served via localServer is serving http and the remote server uses https missing Cors allowancies. A quick and dirty solution would be:
Set the header in the page directly using a templating language like PHP. Keep in mind there can be no HTML before your header or it will fail.

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com"); ?>
```

You should check wether your dev-browser uses any "anti local cors" extension or the browser is started with no cors security enabled. That might explain why local works /kiosk not.
If you rule out option 2 more info on the server to server policy scenario is needed to help any further.

Comment: problem solved after a little fight with the kiosk. brilliant!!!!!!!! THANKS.